# Dynamic div height based on other divs dynamic heights

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar with a search field, two lists and a text div. The height of the search field and the text div is always the same but the heights of the two lists are unknown (meaning they change).

I wonder if there is some way, with only CSS, to make the height of the first div dynamic so it changes depending on the height of the browser window and the height/number of items in the seconds list. The second list could have anywhere between 0 and 20 items in it with a max-height of 40% of the entire page height.

```
<style>
   body, html {
       height: 100 % ;margin: 0;padding: 0;
   }

   ul {
       list - style: none;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }

   #sidebar {
       max - height: 100 % ;
       overflow: hidden;
       width: 300 px;
   }

   #inputContainer {
       height: 50 px;
       max - height: 50 px;
       overflow: hidden;
       background: #eee;
   }

   #firstList 
   {
       background: #ddd
   }

   #secondList 
   {
       width: 100 % ;
       background: #bbb;
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 120 px;
       width: 300 px;
   }

   #firstList ul 
   {
       max - height: 230 px; /*THIS SHOULD NOT BE A STATIC NUMBER*/
       overflow - y: scroll;
   }

   #secondList ul 
   {
       overflow - y: scroll
       max - height: 40 % ;
       min - height: 200 px;
   }

   #otherBox 
   {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0 px;
       background: #333;
          color:# fff;
       height: 100 px;
       width: 300 px;
   }
```

I've created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VYcbswJep4xtcrpJ20k3?p=preview) to demonstrate what I would like to do.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using `flex` model for doing this.

*Relevant CSS*:

```
#sidebar { 
    height:100%; overflow:hidden; width:300px; 
    display: flex;           /* Make the container a flex box */
    flex-direction: column;  /* Children will flow in column */
}
#inputContainer {
    flex: 1 1 50px;          /* can grow, can shrink, accommodate in 50px */
    background:#eee;
}
#firstList{ 
    flex: 1 1 100%;          /* can grow, can shrink, can go upto 100% if available */
    background:#ddd; 
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
#secondList{
    flex: 0 0 20%;           /* cannot grow, cannot shrink, fixed at 20% */
    background:#bbb;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}      
#otherBox{
    flex: 0 0 100px;         /* cannot grow, cannot shrink, fixed at 100px */
    background:#333; color:#fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have updated your Plunker here: ***http://plnkr.co/edit/oVB5Mbu4nU58UjYBFPpC?p=preview***

Also a Fiddle, so you can change height: ***http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/96h4wmkf/3/***

Hope that helps.

.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that flex existed. The only problem is, I forgot to mention it in my question, that I need it to work for IE8  and flex is not supported until IE10 or 11.

Comment: @gusper: You could perhaps use `display: table`, that should work in IE8+. Let me give it a spin in a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a proportional heigth for every element, for example set the following heigths to your elements:

```
#inputContainer{
    height:5%;
...
}

#firstList ul{
    height:40%; 
...
}

#secondList ul{
    max-height:40%;
...
}

#otherBox{
    ...
    height:15%;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Give your div an auto height and and an auto overflow :

```
#firstList ul{
    max-height:230px; /*THIS SHOULD NOT BE A STATIC NUMBER*/
    overflow:auto;
    height:auto;
  }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that in this case. The height of inputContainer and otherBox must be set to a fixed number of pixels.

Comment: @gusper Ok the give it (the second div) an auto height, look at my edit.